# Python nested dictionary function refactoring

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I have a dictionary that contains a bunch of key/value pairs where some of the keys are strings and others are more dictionaries, and so on.

Here's an example dictionary that I'm working with:

```
{'1': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'}},
 '10': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1194', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1194', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1194', 'state': 'T'}},
 '11': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1195', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1195', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1195', 'state': 'T'}},
 '12': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1196', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1196', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1196', 'state': 'T'}},
 '13': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1197', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1197', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1197', 'state': 'T'}},
 '14': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1198', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1198', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1198', 'state': 'T'}},
 '15': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1199', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1199', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1199', 'state': 'T'}},
 '16': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1200', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1200', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1200', 'state': 'T'}},
 '17': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1201', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1201', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1201', 'state': 'T'}},
 '18': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1202', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1202', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1202', 'state': 'T'}},
 '19': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'}},
 '2': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'}},
 '20': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'}},
 '21': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '949', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '949', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '949', 'state': 'T'}},
 '22': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '954', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '954', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '954', 'state': 'T'}},
 '23': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'}},
 '24': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '554', 'state': 'T'}},
 '25': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1203', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1203', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1203', 'state': 'T'}},
 '26': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1204', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1204', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1204', 'state': 'T'}},
 '27': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1220', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1220', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1220', 'state': 'T'}},
 '28': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1221', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1221', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1221', 'state': 'T'}},
 '29': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1222', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1222', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1222', 'state': 'T'}},
 '3': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'}},
 '30': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1223', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1223', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1223', 'state': 'T'}},
 '31': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1224', 'state': 'T'},
        '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1224', 'state': 'T'},
        '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1224', 'state': 'T'}},
 '32': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '33': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '34': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '35': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '36': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '37': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '38': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '39': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '4': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '590', 'state': 'T'}},
 '40': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '41': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '42': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '43': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '44': {'0': {'state': 'F'}, '1': {'state': 'F'}, '2': {'state': 'F'}},
 '5': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'}},
 '6': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'}},
 '7': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'}},
 '8': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1010', 'state': 'T'}},
 '9': {'0': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1193', 'state': 'T'},
       '1': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1193', 'state': 'T'},
       '2': {'hl': '', 'object_id': '1193', 'state': 'T'}},
 'asset_no': '',
 'atags': {'0': {'tag': '$rackid_662'}, '1': {'tag': '$any_rack'}},
 'comment': '',
 'etags': {'21': {'id': '21',
                  'parent_id': '15',
                  'tag': 'DevIT',
                  'time': '1395166273',
                  'user': 'towens-admin'},
           '23': {'id': '23',
                  'parent_id': '9',
                  'tag': 'Internap SEF003',
                  'time': '1395166273',
                  'user': 'towens-admin'}},
 'has_problems': 'no',
 'height': '44',
 'id': '662',
 'isDeletable': '',
 'itags': {'15': {'id': '15',
                  'is_assignable': 'no',
                  'parent_id': '',
                  'refcnt': {'total': '0'},
                  'tag': 'IT Owner',
                  'trace': {}},
           '9': {'id': '9',
                 'is_assignable': 'no',
                 'parent_id': '',
                 'refcnt': {'total': '0'},
                 'tag': 'Site',
                 'trace': {}}},
 'location_id': '374',
 'location_name': 'Internap, SEF003',
 'mountedObjects': {'0': '590',
                    '1': '1010',
                    '10': '1201',
                    '11': '1202',
                    '12': '554',
                    '13': '949',
                    '14': '954',
                    '15': '1203',
                    '16': '1204',
                    '17': '1220',
                    '18': '1221',
                    '19': '1222',
                    '2': '1193',
                    '20': '1223',
                    '21': '1224',
                    '3': '1194',
                    '4': '1195',
                    '5': '1196',
                    '6': '1197',
                    '7': '1198',
                    '8': '1199',
                    '9': '1200'},
 'name': '13',
 'realm': 'rack',
 'row_id': '375',
 'row_name': 'B02-J'}
```

What I need to extract the first key in the following pattern:

```
cabinet['25']['0']['object_id']
```

here's my code:

```
def get_RU(self, hostname):
        host_id = unicode(self.get_id(hostname))
        cab_no = int(self.depot[host_id]['rack_id'])
        cabinet = self.admin.get_rack(cab_no)
        cabinet_name = cabinet['name']
        for key in cabinet.keys():
            if type(cabinet[key]) == dict:
                for k in cabinet[key].keys():
                    if k == '0' and cabinet[key][k]['object_id'] == host_id:
                        return key, cabinet_name
```

What I'm trying to do is either use recursion, or figure out a way to refactor the code so that it's cleaner. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use classes to represent your objects, instead of storing everything as raw data in dictionaries - this will be a lot cleaner. Anyway, this is off-topic, please consider posting on Code Review.

Comment: Or use JSON format, that'll be easier to work with.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza JSON is nice, but what would change if you use JSON here? You would anyway turn it into dictionary and end up with the same task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite difficult structure. I hope, I understood your problem properly.

## Requirements review

Your data are hiding identity of a host (your `key`) so your search goes:

`hostname` -> `host_id` -> (cabinet data structure)[?`key`?]

And the condition for having proper `key` is, that (keydata)["0"]["object_id"] == `host_id`

## What can be rewritten

### Do not loop for item with known key

You can simplify:

```
for k in cabinet[key].keys():
   if k == '0' and cabinet[key][k]['object_id'] == host_id:
      pass #do something
```

to:

```
if cabinet[key]["0"]['object_id'] == host_id:
    pass #do something
```

### Test of value type

Your type of value type:

```
type(val) == dict
```

can be rewritten to:

```
isinstance(val, dict)
```

### Looping over keys in a dictionary

```
for key in dct.keys():
    print key
```

is usually written as:

```
for key in dct:
    print key
```

### Skip test of `dict` type

This relies on your data being correct. Ignore this, if you cannot rely on it.

## Rewriting function

Here goes your original function:

```
def get_RU(self, hostname):
        host_id = unicode(self.get_id(hostname))
        cab_no = int(self.depot[host_id]['rack_id'])
        cabinet = self.admin.get_rack(cab_no)
        cabinet_name = cabinet['name']
        for key in cabinet.keys():
            if type(cabinet[key]) == dict:
                for k in cabinet[key].keys():
                    if k == '0' and cabinet[key][k]['object_id'] == host_id:
                        return key, cabinet_name
```

new version:

```
def get_RU(self, hostname):
    host_id = unicode(self.get_id(hostname))
    cab_no = int(self.depot[host_id]['rack_id'])
    cabinet = self.admin.get_rack(cab_no)
    cabinet_name = cabinet['name']
    for key in cabinet:
        if cabinet[key]['0']['object_id'] == host_id:
            return key, cabinet_name
```

In case, you really cannot prevent problem with key values not being `dict`, you may add try/catch

```
def get_RU(self, hostname):
    host_id = unicode(self.get_id(hostname))
    cab_no = int(self.depot[host_id]['rack_id'])
    cabinet = self.admin.get_rack(cab_no)
    cabinet_name = cabinet['name']
    for key in cabinet:
        try:
            if cabinet[key]['0']['object_id'] == host_id:
                return key, cabinet_name
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            continue
```

## Correcting your data structures

You shall reorganize your data at least in such a way, that the same types of structures live together and do not mix with others. This way you should separate all values for keys "0", "1", "2" etc. from the textual ones. This will make your testing of `dict` type not needed and will also make your code and data easier to read.

## Conclusion

Ugly data structure make code difficult. Try to rectify the data structure, if you can, ideally turning it into dict, where keys will be `host_id` and value the `key` you search for today.

Comment: Wow thank you for the detailed response! As for the structure of the dict itself, this is a dump from Racktables, and the structure is what the racktables API gave me. It's just a mess...I'm trying to deal with it as best I can, but that's the structure given to me via the API. Unfortunately your code does not work, because if the key in cabinet is NOT a dict, then it will fail, so I need a way of recursively checking keys in dicts and finding the pattern while ignoring non-dict keys.

Comment: @digitalsy OK. Added try/catch around the problematic lines. It is often faster then testing the type over and over. Note, that I did not test the code, so there might exist some minor problems (but I did my best).

Comment: That's actually perfect. Thanks, I like that solution a lot. I was trying to go down the path of using recursion in a function, but that got complicated real quick. This works nicely!